# Updating a Code Signing Identity in Xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

I am coding an iPhone app using Xcode 4.2.

My iPhone development provisioning profile expired. When I try to build and run my app on my iPhone, I get a message saying: Code Sign error: "Provisioning profile '(expired provisioning profile number)' can't be found"

I went to the iOS developer provisioning portal, renewed the provisioning profile, and downloaded it.

In Xcode I opened up the Organizer window. I deleted the expired provisioning profile, and added the renewed provisioning profile. (They both have the same name).

In my project Build Settings, under Code Signing Identity, I set the provisioning profile to the name that I want (which is the same as the expired profile name) and try to build, and I get the same error message, with the expired provisioning profile number. I can't find the renewed provisioning profile in the list that pops up when I click on the Code Signing Identity table cells in the Build Settings.

How do I set the Code Signing Identity to the Provisioning Profile that I want?

Answer (score 1):

Try Clean all Targets and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The provisioning profile can be set for the "Project" and "Target" make sure you set them both.

Also delete all profiles and use automatic device provisioning in xcode to import profiles, which sounds like what you did.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have tried to change the provisioning profile in both the Project and the Target. The problem is that the provisioning profile that is available in list that pops up when I'm trying to set it is the old one (that I've already deleted from the Organizer window)

Answer (score 0):

Valid development profiles need to be installed on the device itself.  I have not had one expire so I am not sure if putting it in the organizer will cause it to be copied across.

You can check in your phone menu SETTINGS>GENERAL>PROFILES.  If it is still showing as expired then the updated one has not been copied across.  To copy it across open iTunes on your computer and go to the apps screen for your device, then drag the provisioning profile into there.  Once that is done resync your device and it should appear on your phone.